# How to suppress a Text Object based on header value in Crystal Report?

Tags: text, crystal-reports, header, hide, suppress

How to suppress a Text Object field in Crystal Report based on Header Value.
I have 2 text object fields below the Header and I want to suppress one or other based on my header.

I.e. my header is dynamic and it gets different header value.

CASE 1. In certain case if the header is "ABC" then I want to suppress or hide the 1st text object.
CASE 2. If the header is "DEF" then I want to suppress or hide the 2nd text object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress just a field and not the entire header:

1. Right click on the first text object
2. Select **Format Text** from the menu
3. On the Common tab, find the checkbox labeled **Suppress**. Don't check it though.
4. Instead, click on the **x+2** button on the right side.

   *Note: It is quite far away from the Suppress checkbox it belongs to. See screenshot below for help with finding the button.*

[image]

5. In the formula box that appears, type your condition for suppressing the text box. For example, if you want to suppress the text field if the header is "ABC" then you may want to enter the following:

   ```
   {@HeaderField} = "ABC"
   ```

   6. Repeat for the next text field.

However, there may be an easier way for you to go about this. Instead of having two text objects, create one formula with an IF-THEN-ELSE statement within to determine which text is displayed.

For example:

```
If {groupname} = "ABC" then "first set of text"
Else if {groupname} = "DEF" then "second set of text"
Else "Error"
```

or

```
If {groupname} = "ABC" then "first set of text"
Else "second set of text"
```

or

```
Select {groupname}
Case "ABC": "first set of text"
Case "DEF": "second set of text"
Default: "Error"
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like the if else code gives error "a Boolean is required ". I have something like this "  DL.NO. 20-MH-PZ2-197950 21-MH-PZ2-197951 20B-MH-PZ2-197952 21B-MH-PZ2-197953 20C-MH-PZ2-197954 N.D.P.S.-2-MH PZ2 20F-MH-PZ2-202109 20G-MH-PZ2-202110"  similarly i have another set of this and depending upon a header i have to insert these..please help

Comment: Hi Abhiro! I am glad my answer provided some assistance. In regards to your last comment, were you placing the IF-THEN-ELSE statement in the suppression section of the group properties or were you entering the statement as a formula that would act as a field? The example in step 5 of my answer above goes in the suppression section and the examples I posted with IF-THEN logic would be added as a Formula Field instead.